# Ng-template with ng-repeat shows empty object

Tags: angularjs

I want to do is to show cities in combo box. On each city selection, i need to show students belonging to that selected city in table.

the table is in ng-template, hence when i choose the city from dropdown box, that template should load the students.

please follow the code below

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"></link>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function(){
            angular.module("myApp",[]);
                angular.module("myApp").controller("myCtrl",myCtrl);
                angular.module("myApp").factory("StudentService",StudentService);
            myCtrl.$inject = ["$scope","$log","StudentService","$timeout"];

            function StudentService(){
                var obj = new Object();
                var studentMap = new Object();
                obj.getStudents = getStudents;
                obj.getCities = getCities;

                studentMap["New York"] = [];
                studentMap["Barbados"] = [];
                studentMap["Istambul"] = [];

                studentMap["New York"].push({"name" : "Sankalp Kunder", "branch" : "Mechanical Engineering"});
                studentMap["New York"].push({"name" : "Sunil Tandel", "branch" : "Instrumentation Engineering"});
                studentMap["New York"].push({"name" : "Shamshuddin Ahmed", "branch" : "Production Engineering"});
                studentMap["New York"].push({"name" : "Samir Gupta", "branch" : "Computer Engineering"});

                studentMap["Barbados"].push({"name" : "Vaibhav Patil", "branch" : "Fashion Designing"});
                studentMap["Barbados"].push({"name" : "Suresh Owhal", "branch" : "Marketing Managment"});
                studentMap["Barbados"].push({"name" : "Kavita Nandgaonkar", "branch" : "History and Litrature"});
                studentMap["Barbados"].push({"name" : "Swapnali Joshi", "branch" : "Commerce"});
                studentMap["Barbados"].push({"name" : "Vithhal Gaikwad", "branch" : "Law"});

                studentMap["Istambul"].push({"name" : "Salim Khan", "branch" : "Law"});
                studentMap["Istambul"].push({"name" : "Aslam Shaikh", "branch" : "Animal Husbandry"});
                studentMap["Istambul"].push({"name" : "Liyaqat Ali", "branch" : "Carpentary"});
                studentMap["Istambul"].push({"name" : "Suleman Kaskar", "branch" : "Cutting and Polishing"});

                return obj;

                function getStudents(city){
                    return studentMap[city];
                }

                function getCities(){
                    var ct = [];
                    angular.forEach(studentMap,function(value,key){
                        ct.push(key);       
                    });
                    return ct;
                }
            }

            function myCtrl($scope,$log,StudentService,$timeout){
                $log.log("Hi Angular !!!!");
                $scope.cityList = StudentService.getCities();
                $scope.selectedCity = "";
                $scope.selectedStudents = "";
                $scope.templateName = "";

                $scope.getStudents = function(){
                    $scope.templateName = "";
                    $scope.selectedStudents = StudentService.getStudents($scope.selectedCity);
                    $log.log($scope.selectedStudents);
                    $scope.templateName = "studentsTemplate";
                }
            }

        })();       
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="page-header">
            <h3>Dynamic HTML Template Content</h3>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                    <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                    <select ng-model="selectedCity" ng-options="city for city in cityList" 
                        ng-change="getStudents()">
                        <option value="">Select</option>
                    </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <ng-include src="templateName" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="studentsTemplate">
        <table class="table">
            <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Branch</th>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="student in selectedStudents">
            <td>{{student.name}}</td>
            <td>{{student.branch}}</td>
            </tr>   
        </table>
    </script>   
</body>
```

I am able to load the template, but students are not getting displayed.
the rows fetched in template are empty.
I am not able to see property "name" and "branch" in table, they are just empty rows.

i also loaded this example in jsfeedle, please do through it

[Dynamic templating using NG-template](https://jsfiddle.net/rahulshivsharan/m6qps801/3/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The identical code works fine [in this plunker I created](http://plnkr.co/edit/t6npCWw69s4Uc13ZmRPj?p=preview). You're getting an `Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]` in your fiddle, and it probably has to do with how jsfiddle is loading you scripts.

Comment: But my <td></td> in empty in template, I don't know why

Comment: It's not empty when I [run the plunker in chrome](http://i.imgur.com/Ne3Eruq.png)...

Comment: That's odd. It clearly creates the rows for each of the selected students, but it's as if they're empty objects (which they're clearly not in your console). I refactored the code a little bit to pass in the `selectedCity` into the `getStudents` function from the `<select>` field, and you didn't really need either of the `$scope.templateName = "";` lines in your controller, so I took those out. Plunker updated. If that doesn't help, I'm a little at a loss.

Comment: I am running this example on server, its not a stand alone page. it and html page part of Django app . So does this is the case that my td's are empty ?

Comment: In that case, your service needs to make the call to your server and return the students in a promise, but once the client has the student list, you should be able to execute the code without a problem. Are you making another call to your server to get the `selectedStudents`, or just filtering the data you already have on the client?

Comment: the data is just present on the html page, I am not fetching it from server as seen in code snippet in my question. My question is, it doesn't matter if data comes from server or its on same page, the data has to be seen in the "TD" tag, as its getting printed in console. Whether I need to do somthing to $digest, or need to use ngSanitize. Can you please try doing the same thing on a server and see whether you are getting the same problem.